# Why search didn't show up

Tags: wordpress, search

In WordPress I use following code for search from.

In front page it works fine, but in rest of page, when I click the search button, it jump to the front page, I also notice the URL change to

http://www.example.com/post-title/?s=meme

Here is search form.

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="search" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="Search"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the wordpress accepts the following format for searching `http://www.example.com/?s=meme` instead you're using `http://www.example.com/post-title/?s=meme` try the following code

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="">
<input type="search" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="Search"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
```

Comment: By typing `http://www.example.com/?s=meme` in your browser wordpress doesnot search for the word meme on your website?

Comment: Yeah, this works fine, http://www.example.com/?s=meme But when I click the search button, the URL will automatic change to http://www.example.com/post-title/?s=meme